# PythonWebkit default directory listing

Tags: python, webkit, directory-listing

I want to change the default directory listing of the pythonwebkit(the one imported from gi.repository) for an application I am working on. Is there any function/script in webkit that does the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

The code for styling the default directory listing is in the file [net/base/dir_header.html](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/net/base/dir_header.html) and ends up in `chrome.pak` and `chrome_100_percent.pak`.

The [python module data_pack.py](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/tools/grit/grit/format/data_pack.py&exact_package=chromium&ct=rc&cd=3&q=data_pack) can work with these files.

If you want to filter certain file types from the list, you can probably do that in `addRow()`

<s>You will have to use [os.chdir()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) to change the current directory for the whole process. AFAIK, WebKit doesn't keep an internal environment for things like the current folder.</s>

Comment: I wanted to change the directory listing when i browse the local file system from the webkit (as in styling the list and showing only certain types of files in the list) not the current working directory of python. 
Thanks.

Comment: Ah, you mean how to change the CSS styles and the layout of the directory listing page?

Comment: That and the file types that are being displayed on the page.I want to  show only certain types of files in the directory listing.

Comment: You can probably do this by modifying `addRow()`. See my edits.

Comment: The datapack.py is specific to chromium browser. Is there any such file for pythongtk webkit?

Comment: python-webkitgtk are just Python bindings for an installed chrome browser. In my case, it's using libwebkitgtk-3_0-0 which doesn't contain any .pak files :-/ And the library itself is pretty small, so I'm not really sure where they hide this. Please download the sources of the package for your OS and look what you can find in there.